# Add column into sf() dataframe in r?

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I have an sf object as obtained from here.

```
extraWD <- "."
if (!file.exists(file.path(extraWD, "departement.zip"))) {
  githubURL <- "https://github.com/statnmap/blog_tips/raw/master/2018-07-14-introduction-to-mapping-with-sf-and-co/data/departement.zip"
  download.file(githubURL, file.path(extraWD, "departement.zip"))
  unzip(file.path(extraWD, "departement.zip"), exdir = extraWD)
}

departements_L93 <- st_read(dsn = extraWD, 
                            layer = "DEPARTEMENT",
                            quiet = TRUE) %>% st_transform(2154)
```

I want to add another column with values to plot.
How can I add this column while keeping the sf() structure so I can plot it?
If this is not possible, how can I generate the sf() dataframe from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{sf}` package objects are modified dataframes, so any technique you would use for adding a column to a regular dataframe should work.

I recommend either one of the `dplyr::*_join()` family functions to add a column by key, or `dplyr::mutate()` to add a calculated column.

But base R techniques, such as creating a column via the dollar notation, should work too...